# play video in WPF using HTML5 <video> tag

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have an mp4 formatted video that I want to play in WPF using HTML5  tag. OGG videos are playing smoothly in this case but with MP4 video i am getting just a blank screen

Here is my HTML which works fine with OGG

```
<html>
<video class="video" style="height: 56%; width: 100%" data-bind="videoEditorCasparCG:{videoControlElement:videoControlElement},attr:{src: vidsrc}">
<source src="" type="video/mp4" />
    <p>
    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 videso...
    </p>
</video>
<html>
```

Comment: you should post a code snipped - so we can see what you got

Comment: <video class="video" style="height: 56%; width: 100%" data-bind="videoEditorCasparCG:{videoControlElement:videoControlElement},attr:{src: vidsrc}">
 <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
        <p>
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 videso...
        </p>
    </video>

Answer (score 1):

The default webbrowser in .net is some old version of internet explorer, so alot of stuff won't work as expected. You could use some wrappers for .net that use chromium, something like http://www.awesomium.com/. With this you can inject html codes directly in the browser and do alot of stuff